# Is there a way to export a blog from Stackbit?

Tags: content-management-system

I have tried Stackbit and I have built a blog in two minutes. But I don´t find any export option. Is there a way to export a blog from Stackbit?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found it. In your Github project there is a project-name/src/pages/posts/ folder